# JOIN query for retrieving the last post from specific categories

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have the following code for Wordpress:

```
SELECT terms.*, posts.ID as post_ID
FROM wp_terms terms 
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy term_taxonomy 
    ON terms.term_id = term_taxonomy.term_id
JOIN wp_term_relationships term_relationships 
    ON ( term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id 
        AND term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' )
JOIN wp_posts posts
    ON ( posts.ID = term_relationships.object_id 
        AND posts.post_type='post'
        AND posts.post_status='publish')
WHERE terms.term_id=19 OR terms.term_id=20 OR terms.term_id=21 OR terms.term_id=22
GROUP BY terms.term_id
ORDER BY posts.post_modified_gmt DESC
```

I want to retrieve the last post from specific categories. But it returns the first post of each category. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the DESC keyword.

Comment: The same results with different sort...but again the first post per cat

Comment: I m still working to solve the problem, but i cant find a solution. I m trying to insert "order by" statements into JOIN but it returns error.